# 3D object blinks in and out of visibility through canvas

Tags: unity, rendering, unity-ui, visibility-determination

In the Menu scene I have canvas with buttons and some 3D objects that are visible in camera's view.
However one object - "the red prompt Arrow" is jumping in and out of visibility. Like here :
[image: Blinking Demonstration]

It occurs both in editor (Game/Scene tabs) and in play.

Here are my camera settings on a better quality image :
[image: Settings of camera in editor]

The arrow seems to be covered by the canvas when it disspears as we can see the outline in editor :
[image: Arrow Outline]

There is no code involved in rendering arrow or canvas other than it's existence in the editor already demands by default. (So no attached scripts of that nature - the arrow is a freshly added 3D object )
The arrow is technically a prefab.

I already tried to move it closer to the camera (Z axis) or changing it's thickness, but nothing worked. Do you have any idea what is happening ?

Comment: <Answer to Gregory'ies comment that dissapeared too (sic!)>
Oh, OK. I didn't know that the ordering works this way here. I was under the impression that it works within the canvas and the canvas itself is just an object in that space with similar ordering. 
However it does not change one bit if I place `leftMenu_RedPrompt` as first child of the canvas.

Comment: It appears that if I change the ordering of canvas to negative value, then the arrow appears. But I have no idea why the arrow alone has this ordering problem and the spheres don't. I'll dig into the ordering subject and maybe arrive with an answer later.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment because I'd missed that this was a 3D object, which does not use canvas UI ordering, so it was not strictly applicable here.